# Reference a date field, auto-calculation in Word-2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, templates

I'm using a Word 2007 template for a weekly activity report.

It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to be able to just specify one date, say the first date of the week, and the others would adjust accordingly. So that the "To" date would be the `entered date+5`, Monday would be the same `entered date` (different format), Tuesday would be `entered date+1`, etc.

I can only see automatic dates in input fields, but those can be edited by hand, so I guess a "CreationDate" field *would work*, but ideally a custom date if one's available, no update required (except to referencees). **But how do you reference another field and perform calculations on them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surround the field with a bookmark and then use fields such as REF. However, performing calculations on dates is more complex then it sounds. Check out the [following site](http://addbalance.com/word/datefields2.htm) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: I think you're going to get a Necromancer badge for this. I ended up picking the proper tool for this, which was Excel. All I had to do was convince management that it was better suited.

Comment: @MPelletier, Glad to hear you found the answer :) I agree, Excel is a much more suitable tool for this kind of thing.